# Declaring a global struct that is created inside a function

Tags: c, struct, global

I have a number of functions that need to share a struct but as the size of the struct is variable I get an error if I declare it outside of all functions, is there a way to declare a struct inside a specific function and have it accessible to all others?

This is what I have so far:

header file:

```
//  functions.h
struct Pixel
{
    int x; // x axis of pixel location
    int y; // y axis of pixel location
    int r; //red
    int g; //green
    int b; //blue
};

//failed attempt at declaring pixels as global
extern struct Pixel pixels[];
```

the struct pixels[] is defined inside a separate file which has all the functions that utilize it and includes the above mentioned header file

```
int Parser(FILE* file)
{
    // lots of foo 

    // structure declaration where linecount is a variable number generated 
    // in another function but declared globally
    struct Pixel pixels[linecount];
}
```

Comment: Your structure is not variable. Your array size is. Use malloc/free.

Comment: In general, using global variables is seen as bad practice. Are you sure you need them? Why you don't pass data through parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare an extern variable, then the variable definition must be in file scope( global ). But your definition is in function scope( local ).

This means the declaration `extern struct Pixel pixels[];` in a header  must be accompanied by a definition `struct Pixel pixels[15];` in a .c file( and in file scope ) where SIZE( 15 in this case ) is a constant expression. Constant expression cannot be a variable or even a const variable.

If you want the size of the array `pixels` to be defined at runtime, then you have to change your array to a pointer.

```
extern struct Pixel* pixels;   //header
```

```
struct Pixel* pixels = NULL ;   //file scope
```

```
if( !pixels )    //function scope
    pixels = malloc( sizeof( struct Pixel ) * linecount ) ;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this error is related to the same problem but I got this from my linker: 'duplicate symbol _selector in:
    /Volumes/ML/Users/foo/lightstick.build/Debug/lightstick.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/arduino-serial.o
    /Volumes/ML/Users/foo/lightstick.build/Debug/lightstick.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/functions.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)' I'm not sure how to get more information on the error. thanks!

Comment: @AbdullahMaskari No idea. Comments are not the best place to ask a new unrelated question. Try here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can do it by using pointer to structure and dynamically allocate memory for that pointer in any one of your function.

```
extern struct Pixel *pixels; // In header file
struct Pixel *pixels = NULL; // Global
```

Since `pixels` is declared global the allocated memory is accessible to any of the function.

```
void foo()
{

     pixels = malloc(sizeof(struct Pixel)*linecount);
     //Do some stuff  
}
```

But do not use global variable until it is necessary.

Comment: +1: I think your answer is ok, but you could explain a little more. Anyway, probably what the OP want to do is a bad practice (several global variables...).

Comment: @pablo1977; Yes. I do agree. Usin global variable is not a good idea.

Comment: You need to add a global declaration of pixels, as self did in his answer.